# Build & Distributing an iOS app with Codemagic CI / CD

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, cicd, codemagic

I am trying to setup a complete **CI / CD workflow with Codemagic** on my GitLab repository for my **Flutter project** in order to distribute and publish the **iOS and Android apps on Firebase App Distribution**.

So far I successfully manage to have it work for Android, however it won't work for iOS although the job completes successfully on Codemagic.

**Looking at the generated artifacts:**

[image: Generated artifacts upon successful build]

To my suprise, I noticed that Codemagic generated a zip file containing an `.app` file. To my understanding, such is the file extension for MacOS Applications, not iOS applications which is `.ipa`.

**I don't even have the right plan to build MacOS Apps:**

[image: targeted platforms]

Before posting here, I looked at tutorials and various somewhat outdated guides because all of them showed an option, in the `build settings` for a checkbox titled "Flutter build ipa" that does not exist on my CI / CD.

I don't understand where I got things wrong.

---

Here a few screenshots of the workflow setup:

**Build setup:**

[image: Build setup]

**Firebase Distribution setup**

Thanks in advance for the help.
[image]

Comment: You probably just need to change the .zip filename so it has a .ipa extension

Comment: @Clive, already tried it and this is the error I am getting when manually upoloading to Firebase App Distribution: `There's been an error parsing your app's info.plist. Ensure you are uploading a valid IPA and try again.`. Also, having to have to rename it manually defeat the purpose of autonomous distribution, doesn't it?

Comment: Well, yes. I just remember, at one point at least, that manual steps to building an .ipa involved exporting a .app, putting it in a folder, zipping the folder, then changing the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you setup your iOS build with the required configuration for code signing? as having the `Runner.app.zip` as build artifact is the normal result of having setup your iOS build to be a debug build and debug builds are only for running on an iOS Simulator.

For example if I setup a Codemagic project to do debug builds for iOS, ie. in the builds log you see for the build step:

```
== Building for iOS ==

> flutter build ios --debug --no-codesign

... [REDACTED] ...

Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                           35.8s
Built /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app.
```

then as you can see in the log, the expected artifact produced on successful build is `Runner.app.zip`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not know I was supposed to sign the iOS app. Does that require an active pro account at Apple (with the yearly fee)?

Comment: @Mackovich yes, you need an Apple Developer account in order to have a signing certificate from Apple, to sign your ipa file. This Codelab covers the topic in more detail, note that it specifically says that you need a paid Apple developer account: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/appdistribution-udid-collection#0